# How to crawl question and answer of Google People Also Ask with Selenium and Python for a quantity that is more than the default output of Google?

Tags: python, selenium, parsing

I found a good [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70053266/18132919), but it works on the number of questions and answers that Google gives by default, but for example I need more.

I am a novice developer on Python.
How do I get more questions and answers?
Do I have to implement a click first to disclose the required amount and then parse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code parse the questions appearing on screen, then asks if you want to parse more questions or not. If you enter `y` then it clicks on the last question's button so that more are loaded in the page. The questions are stored in the list `questions`, the answers in the list `answers`

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

your_path = '...'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(your_path))

driver.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=How%20to%20make%20bakery%3F&source=hp&ei=j0aZYYjRAvja2roPrcWcyAU&iflsig=ALs-wAMAAAAAYZlUn4NMUPjfIpQmrXSmjIDnaWjJXWIJ&ved=0ahUKEwjI1JDn0Kf0AhV4rVYBHa0iB1kQ4dUDCAc&uact=5&oq=How%20to%20make%20bakery%3F&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgAEBMyBAgAEBMyBAgAEBMyBAgAEBMyBAgAEBMyBAgAEBMyBAgAEBMyBAgAEBMyBAgAEBMyBAgAEBNQAFgAYJMDaABwAHgAgAF-iAF-kgEDMC4xmAEAoAECoAEB&sclient=gws-wiz')

questions, answers = [], []
while 1:
    for idx,question in enumerate(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id*='RELATED_QUESTION']")):
        if idx >= len(questions): # skip already parsed questions
            questions.append(question.text)
            txt = ''
            for answer in question.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id*='WEB_ANSWERS_RESULT']"):
                txt += answer.get_attribute('innerText')
            answers.append(txt)
    inp = input(f'{idx+1} questions parsed, continue? (y/n)')
    if inp == 'y':
        question.click()
        time.sleep(2)
    else:
        break
```